# How to use webpack with any backend language except Node?

Tags: webpack

I have an application which renders html server side. It also has some api endpoints which are called from javascript code.

The number of JS files are growing in numbers and, as each route requires some JS files, so the number of requests that browser makes is also increasing.

I want to bundle the common javascript files like jquery and bootstrap, and other js files as per their functions. I used Gulp to do it, and the problem with it was that my JS didn't run as expected; I had to reorder the code in the bundle.

I then came across Webpack, saw some tutorials, followed them line by line and it looks good to me. But everywhere on the internet, node js and webpack are tied together. Even in docs, they say that I should have an entry file, but mine is not a SPA. My app has different routes which need some base files (jquery and bootstrap) and the files related to that route.

I was unable to find any example on the internet where Webpack is used with Golang or any other language with server side html rendering. So, what is the technique to use webpack in my situation? I only want a bundle or couple of bundles of js and css files which I can use in my html files. Then, whenever any request will come on a route, the html template will be filled with data from the database and I will serve it to the user.

(My app is in Golang, but answer need not be.)

Comment: Please add some formatting/paragraphs to your question. It's currently a wall of text and that makes it very difficult to read

Answer (score 1):

So to use Webpack in your use case with an application that has a lot of server-side rendering.

You essentially want to have an entry file that imports all of the JS and CSS you may want in a single bundle.

You could even have multiple entries that produce multiple bundles containing different JS and CSS for particular pages.

Depending on what libraries you want to include (jQuery and Bootstrap) you will need to have a `webpack.config.js` that is configured with the right loaders in order to load the dependencies of the libraries you want.

These may be things such as fonts, images, stylesheets, and so on.

To start I would have a simple Node.js package with the dependencies you need.

The `dependencies` section of your `package.json` should contain all of you client libraries such as jQuery and Bootstrap.

The  `devDependencies` section of your `package.json` should contain all of the build tools you need in order to build your desired bundle such as Webpack and the loaders your need.

Bootstrap has a [section of their docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/) devoted to how you import it using Webpack.

With things like jQuery you should be importing it in the scripts you've written that use it.

Such as...

```
const $ = require('jquery')

$(() => {
  // Do something $('.here')
})
```